# Inequality involving Expectation 3

Tags: expectation

How do we prove $\mathbf{E} \left(\frac{1}{X} \right) \geq \frac{1}{\mathbf{E}(X)}$ for random variable $X$?

Can we use Jensen's inequality ?

Comment: Is $X>0$ almost surely?

Comment: X is nonnegative

Comment: Then yes, use Jensen's inequality, as $x\mapsto\frac{1}{x}$ is convex over $(0,+\infty)$.

Comment: Please sketch the proof if possible

Comment: Jensen's inequality states that if $\phi$ is a convex function, then $\phi(E(X))\leq E(\phi(X))$. Just take $\phi(x)=\frac{1}{x}$.

Answer (score 1):

[Jensen's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen's_inequality) works since $f(x)=\frac1x$ is convex for $x\gt0$. That is, Jensen says
$$
E(f(X))\ge f(E(X))
$$
One can also use [Cauchy-Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Probability_theory) because
$$
E\left(\frac1X\right)E(X)\ge E(1)^2
$$